# Meteor; How to only show admin page to admins, and make link visible on navbar

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to make an "admin panel" link visible for any users with level higher or equal to 500. My codes:

in routes.js

```
Router.route('/admin', {
    template: 'admin'
      if (Meteor.user().profile.level => '500') {
        return 'admin';
      } else {
        return '404';
      }
    });
```

navbar html

```
<div class="col-md-4">{{#if currentUser}}
                    <li>
                        <a href="/profile/{{steamId}}">
                        <img src="{{steamAvatar}}"/> {{steamPersonaName}}</a>
                        {{#if level => 500}}
                        <a href="/admin">
                        Admin Panel</a>
```

I get these errors:

```
While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   lib/routes.js:27:6: Unexpected token (27:6)

   While processing files with templating (for target web.browser):
   client/templates/layout/layoutDefault.html:27: Expected identifier,
   number, string, boolean, null, or a sub expression enclosed in "(", ")"
   ...           {{#if level => '500'}}
   ...
   ^

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.windows.x86_32):
   lib/routes.js:27:6: Unexpected token (27:6)
```

Comment: should be >=, not =>

Comment: And you should probably use integers, otherwise users with level 7 will also be shown the `admin` template. Of course, you should not count on it as a security measure.

Comment: okay, how do I make a secured version of it?

Comment: I would suggest using alanning:roles meteor package.  It has methods that you could use in your menu to show/hide based on what groups/roles a user has.

Comment: is that secured? because im creatin a site dealing with site 'currency' that when accumulated can be rewarded with real value

Comment: That is a fairly broad topic. Currently, Meteor sends all of the JS to the client, so a client can see all of the templates/views. Don't let clients get data they should not have access to or perform unauthorized actions and don't trust anything coming from the client (publications/methods). There is a lot of material about security around the web (including the meteor guide).